# Count previous rows within range

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, common-table-expression, window-functions

I'd like to determine, for each row, the total number of preceding records within a given time range.

A specific example:

```
clone=# \d test
              Table "pg_temp_2.test"
 Column |            Type             | Modifiers 
--------+-----------------------------+-----------
 id     | bigint                      | 
 date   | timestamp without time zone |
```

I'd like to know for each `date` the count of rows within '1 hour previous' to that `date`.
Can I do this with a window function? Something like (pseudo-code, not working):

```
SELECT id, date
     , count(*) OVER (HAVING previous_rows.date >= (date - '1 hour'::interval))  -- ?
FROM test;
```

I can write this by joining test against itself, as below - but this won't scale with large tables.

```
SELECT a.id, a.date, count(b.*)-1 
FROM test a, test b 
WHERE (b.date >= a.date - '1 hour'::interval AND b.date < a.date)
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 2;
```

Is this something I could do with a recursive query? Or with a regular Common Table Expression (CTE)?

Comment: Note: your 2nd query wont find rows that don't have any matching row (in the previous 1 hour time window) Note2: try not to use `date` as an identifier. It is a reserved word (type name).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Test case

Using `ts` instead of the [reserved word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) `date` as column name. Also "date" is misleading for a *timestamp*.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id  bigint
, ts  timestamp
);
```

### Postgres 11 or newer

Quoting the [release notes for Postgres 11](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/release-11.html#id-1.11.6.27.5.7):

> - Add all window function framing options specified by SQL:2011 (Oliver Ford, Tom Lane)
>
> Specifically, allow `RANGE` mode to use `PRECEDING` and `FOLLOWING` to
> select rows having grouping values within plus or minus the specified
> offset. [...]

So this is simple now. And faster than older workarounds:

```sql
SELECT id, ts
     , count(*) OVER (ORDER BY ts RANGE '1 hour' PRECEDING EXCLUDE CURRENT ROW)
FROM   test
ORDER  BY ts;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rT_ZS56C)

If there can be duplicates in `ts`, you'll have to define how to count those, and possibly do more.

### Postgres 10 or older

You cannot do this cheaply with a plain query, CTEs and window functions - their frame definition is static, but you need a **dynamic frame** (depending on column values).

Generally, you'll have to define lower and upper bound of your window carefully: The following queries *exclude* the current row and *include* the lower border.
There is still a minor difference: the function includes previous peers of the current row, while the correlated subquery excludes them ...

#### [ROM - Roman's query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18175342/939860)

Use CTEs, aggregate timestamps into an array, unnest, count ...
While correct, performance **deteriorates drastically** with more than a hand full of rows. There are a couple of performance killers here. See below.

#### ARR - count array elements

I took Roman's query and tried to streamline it a bit:

- Remove 2nd CTE which is not necessary.
- Transform 1st CTE into subquery, which is faster.
- Direct `count()`  instead of re-aggregating into an array and counting with `array_length()`.

But array handling is expensive, and performance still **deteriorates badly** with more rows.

```sql
SELECT id, ts
     , (SELECT count(*)::int - 1
        FROM   unnest(dates) x
        WHERE  x >= sub.ts - interval '1h') AS ct
FROM (
   SELECT id, ts
        , array_agg(ts) OVER(ORDER BY ts) AS dates
   FROM   test
   ) sub;
```

#### COR - correlated subquery

You *could* solve it with a simple correlated subquery. A lot faster, but still ...

```sql
SELECT id, ts
     , (SELECT count(*)
        FROM   test t1
        WHERE  t1.ts >= t.ts - interval '1h'
        AND    t1.ts < t.ts) AS ct
FROM   test t
ORDER  BY ts;
```

#### FNC - Function

Loop over rows in chronological order with a `row_number()` in **plpgsql function** and combine that with a [**cursor**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-cursors.html) over the same query, spanning the desired time frame. Then we can just subtract row numbers:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION running_window_ct(_intv interval = '1 hour')
  RETURNS TABLE (id bigint, ts timestamp, ct int)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   cur   CURSOR FOR
         SELECT t.ts + _intv AS ts1
              , row_number() OVER (ORDER BY t.ts ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS rn
         FROM   test t
         ORDER  BY t.ts;
   rec   record;
   rn    int;
BEGIN
   OPEN cur;
   FETCH cur INTO rec;
   ct := -1;  -- init

   FOR id, ts, rn IN
      SELECT t.id, t.ts
           , row_number() OVER (ORDER BY t.ts ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
      FROM   test t ORDER BY t.ts
   LOOP
      IF rec.ts1 >= ts THEN
         ct := ct + 1;
      ELSE
         LOOP
            FETCH cur INTO rec;
            EXIT WHEN rec.ts1 >= ts;
         END LOOP;
         ct := rn - rec.rn;
      END IF;

      RETURN NEXT;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

Why `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`? See:

- [Find first 3 orders for each customer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72533266/find-first-3-orders-for-each-customer/72824267#72824267)

Call with default interval of one hour:

```
SELECT * FROM running_window_ct();
```

Or with any interval:

```
SELECT * FROM running_window_ct('2 hour - 3 second');
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/I1JckQkd)
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/5faffd/1)</sub>

### Benchmark

With the table from above I ran a quick benchmark on my old test server: (PostgreSQL 9.1.9 on Debian).

```
-- TRUNCATE test;
INSERT INTO test
SELECT g, '2013-08-08'::timestamp
         + g * interval '5 min'
         + random() * 300 * interval '1 min' -- halfway realistic values
FROM   generate_series(1, 10000) g;

CREATE INDEX test_ts_idx ON test (ts);
ANALYZE test;  -- temp table needs manual analyze
```

I varied the **bold** part for each run and took the best of 5 with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

**100 rows**
ROM: 27.656 ms
ARR: 7.834 ms
COR: 5.488 ms
FNC: **1.115 ms**

**1000 rows**
ROM: 2116.029 ms
ARR: 189.679 ms
COR: 65.802 ms
FNC: **8.466 ms**

**5000 rows**
ROM: 51347 ms !!
ARR: 3167 ms
COR: 333 ms
FNC: **42 ms**

**100000 rows**
ROM: DNF
ARR: DNF
COR: 6760 ms
FNC: **828 ms**

The function is the clear victor. It is fastest by an order of magnitude and scales best.
Array handling cannot compete.

Comment: Brilliant analysis there Erwin. I appreciate the effort you've taken to illustrate the differences. In the mean time I went with the plpgsql approach, as I needed to implement so other logic around this idea.  As you suggested, performance is markedly better than I had  hoped for.

Comment: Is this still valid with the window function OVER `frame_clause` options ? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS like `range between value preceding and current row`

Comment: @Davos: Since Postgres 11, there is a better way. I updated above answer.

Answer (score 2):

**update** My previous attempt is not perform well, because it combine all elements into array, and that's not what I wanted to do. So here's an updated version - it's not perform as well as self join or function with cursors, but it's not so terrible as my previous one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION agg_array_range_func
(
  accum anyarray,
  el_cur anyelement,
  el_start anyelement,
  el_end anyelement
)
returns anyarray
as
$func$
declare
    i int;
    N int;
begin
    N := array_length(accum, 1);
    i := 1;
    if N = 0 then
        return array[el_cur];
    end if;
    while i <= N loop
        if accum[i] between el_start and el_end then
            exit;
        end if;
        i := i + 1;
    end loop;
    return accum[i:N] || el_cur;
end;
$func$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE AGGREGATE agg_array_range
(
    anyelement,
    anyelement,
    anyelement
)
(
  SFUNC=agg_array_range_func,
  STYPE=anyarray
);

select
    id, ts,
    array_length(
        agg_array_range(ts, ts - interval '1 hour', ts) over (order by ts)
    , 1) - 1
from test;
```

I've tested in on my local machine and in sqlfiddle, and actually self join performed best (I was surprised, my results are not the same as Erwin), then Erwin function and then this aggregate. You can test it yourself in [**sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/8c8a4/1)

**previous** I'm still learning PostgreSQL, but I like all the possibilities very much. If it was SQL Server, I'd use select for xml and select from xml. I don't know how to do it in PostreSQL, but there is much better things for that task - arrays!!!

So here's my CTE with windowed functions (I think it would work incorrectly if there's duplicate dates in the table, and I also don't know if it would perform better than self join):

```
with cte1 as (
    select
        id, ts,
        array_agg(ts) over(order by ts asc) as dates
    from test
), cte2 as (
    select
       c.id, c.ts,
       array(
        select arr
        from (select unnest(dates) as arr) as x
        where x.arr >= c.ts - '1 hour'::interval
       ) as dates
   from cte1 as c
)
select c.id, c.ts, array_length(c.dates, 1) - 1 as cnt
from cte2 as c
```

see [**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/edbbe/30)

hope that helps

Comment: While this works correctly, performance deteriorates drastically with more than a few rows. Consider explanation, alternatives & benchmark in my updated answer.

Comment: thanks @ErwinBrandstetter +1 for you, I have another idea but have no time to try it, may be a little later