# Rolling count of rows withing time interval

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, subquery

For an analysis I need to aggregate the rows of a single table depending on their creation time. Basically, I want to know the count of orders that have been created within a certain period of time before the current order. Can't seem to find the solution to this.

Table structure:

| order_id | time_created |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 00:00 |
| 2 | 00:01 |
| 3 | 00:03 |
| 4 | 00:05 |
| 5 | 00:10 |

Expected result:

| order_id | count within 3 seconds |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Sounds* like an application for [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS). But, sadly, that's not the case. Window frames can only be based on row counts, not on actual column values.

A simple query with `LEFT JOIN` can do the job:

```sql
SELECT t0.order_id
     , count(t1.time_created) AS count_within_3_sec
FROM   tbl      t0
LEFT   JOIN tbl t1 ON t1.time_created BETWEEN t0.time_created - interval '3 sec'
                                          AND t0.time_created
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=78561bccf3b25dcb8fbb5c1014c4550f)*

Does not work with `time` like in your minimal demo, as that does not wrap around. I suppose it's reasonable to assume **`timestamp`** or `timestamptz`.

Since you include each row itself in the count, an `INNER JOIN` would work, too. (`LEFT JOIN` is still more reliable in the face of possible NULL values.)

Or use a `LATERAL` subquery and you don't need to aggregate on the outer query level:

```sql
SELECT t0.order_id
     , t1.count_within_3_sec
FROM   tbl t0
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT count(*) AS count_within_3_sec
   FROM   tbl t1
   WHERE  t1.time_created BETWEEN t0.time_created - interval '3 sec'
                              AND t0.time_created
   ) t1 ON true
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Related:

- [Rolling sum / count / average over date interval](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/107495/3684)

For big tables and many rows in the time frame, a procedural solution that walks through the table *once* will perform better. Like:

- [Window Functions or Common Table Expressions: count previous rows within range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173412/window-functions-or-common-table-expressions-count-previous-rows-within-range/18174102#18174102)
- [Alternatives to broken PL/ruby: convert a warehouse journal table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36612162/alternatives-to-broken-pl-ruby-convert-a-warehouse-journal-table/36659866#36659866)
- [GROUP BY and aggregate sequential numeric values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014577/group-by-and-aggregate-sequential-numeric-values/8014694#8014694)

Comment: Thanks for the edit and query solution. As you already pointed out, for a big table (which unfortunately I have) a procedural solution seems to be the better approach. I am now trying to implement according to your procedural solution with PL/pgSQL.

Comment: Are you sure there is a procedural solution that significantly outperforms the join? I can, of course, iterate over all records and  then query the count of records that is within three seconds, but if I am  not mistaken, that is just as expensive as the join. I have looked into your procedural solution (from your link) and that is a very elegant solution, but it really only works if every record gets mapped to exactly one row in the result, which is not true in my scenario. Maybe I am overlooking something...

Comment: @MikeAndIke: Yes, I am certain. But it's a bit more complex than the example I provided. I investigated and found another related answer (added above). I am actually closing this question as duplicate as the other one answers your question exactly.