# Rolling sum till a certain value is reached, plus calculated duration

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlcommand, cumulative-sum, rolling-computation

I have a requirement where I need to know when the `sum(value)` reaches certain point and calculate duration. Below is the sample table.

```
create table sample (dt timestamp, value real);

insert into sample values
     ('2019-01-20 00:29:43 ',0.29)
    ,('2019-01-20 00:35:06 ',0.31)
    ,('2019-01-20 00:35:50 ',0.41)
    ,('2019-01-20 00:36:32 ',0.26)
    ,('2019-01-20 00:37:20 ',0.33)
    ,('2019-01-20 00:41:30 ',0.42)
    ,('2019-01-20 00:42:28 ',0.35)
    ,('2019-01-20 00:43:14 ',0.52)
    ,('2019-01-20 00:44:18 ',0.25);
```

**Now my requirement is to calculate the cumulative sum of following rows to see when the `sum(value)` reaches above 1.0**. That can require just 1 row or n rows. Once that row is reached, I need to calculate time difference between current row and the row where `sum(value)` reaches above 1.0.

Essentially my desired output is in below format.
For the 1st row, cumulative `sum(value)` is reached at the 3rd row.
For the 2nd row, cumulative `sum(value)` is reached at the 4th row etc.

```
         dt         | value | sum(value)| time_at_sum(value)_1| Duration
---------------------+--------+------------------------------------------
 2019-01-20 00:29:43| 0.29  |   1.01    | 2019-01-20 00:35:50 | 00:06:07
 2019-01-20 00:35:06| 0.31  |   1.31    | 2019-01-20 00:37:20 | 00:02:14 
 2019-01-20 00:35:50| 0.41  |   1.00    | 2019-01-20 00:37:20 | 00:01:30 
 2019-01-20 00:36:32| 0.26  |   1.01    | 2019-01-20 00:41:30 | 00:04:58 
 2019-01-20 00:37:20| 0.33  |   1.10    | 2019-01-20 00:42:28 | 00:05:08 
 2019-01-20 00:41:30| 0.42  |   1.29    | 2019-01-20 00:43:14 | 00:01:44 
 2019-01-20 00:42:28| 0.35  |   1.12    | 2019-01-20 00:44:18 | 00:01:50 
 2019-01-20 00:43:14| 0.52  |   NULL    |  -                  | -
 2019-01-20 00:44:18| 0.25  |   NULL    |  -                  | -
```

Anyone has ideas or pointers on how to deal with above requirement?

Comment: And what does `sum(value)` have to do with the data?

Comment: Its cumulative sum of value column until it reaches 1.0.. Just showing expected output..

Comment: The data you have shown for `value` does not obviously sum to the `sum(value)` examples. Can you edit the description to show the actual computation that leads from `value` to `sum(value)` in your example?

Comment: Hi @bignose, I have edited my request. I manually populated the desired output column. Basically Sum(value) is the cumulative sum of next n number of recorods until it reaches value 1

Comment: `1.00` for `sum(value)` in your result violates your condition `when the sum(value) reaches above 1.0`, which tranlates to `> 1.0`, not `>= 1.0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to solve this **efficiently** is a procedural solution with two cursors:
One [explicit cursor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-cursors.html) and another [implicit cursor of the `FOR` loop](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo()
  RETURNS TABLE (dt timestamp
               , val real
               , sum_value real
               , time_at_sum timestamp
               , duration interval) AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _bound real := 1.0;          -- your bound here
   cur CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM sample s ORDER BY s.dt; -- in chronological order
   s sample;                    -- cursor row 
BEGIN
   OPEN cur;
   FETCH cur INTO time_at_sum, sum_value; -- fetch first row into target

   FOR dt, val IN  -- primary pass over table
      SELECT x.dt, x.value FROM sample x ORDER BY s.dt
   LOOP
      WHILE sum_value <= _bound LOOP
         FETCH cur INTO s;
         IF NOT FOUND THEN  -- end of table
            sum_value := NULL; time_at_sum := NULL;
            EXIT;           -- exits inner loop
         END IF;
         sum_value := sum_value + s.value; 
      END LOOP;
      IF sum_value > _bound THEN  -- to catch end-of-table
         time_at_sum := s.dt;
      END IF;   
      duration := time_at_sum - dt;
      RETURN NEXT;
      sum_value := sum_value - val;  -- subtract previous row before moving on
   END LOOP;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM foo();
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=f3b2fb13dbf83f4742ba75cdb63a3014)*

Should perform nicely since it only needs 2 scans over the table.

Note that I implemented `> _bound` like your description requires, not `>= _bound` like your result indicates. Easy to change either way.

Assumes the value column to be `NOT NULL`.

Related:

- [Window Functions or Common Table Expressions: count previous rows within range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173412/window-functions-or-common-table-expressions-count-previous-rows-within-range/18174102#18174102)

Comment: @acul: I would be very interested in actual times for the function as compared to unutbu's query (along with the number of rows in your table and a rough avg of rows to be aggregated per `sum_value`).

Comment: Hi @Erwin Brandstetter: I will get error saying "ERROR:  value out of range: overflow" on both solutions..

Comment: Is your column `value` in fact defined as `real`? What is the true value of `_bound` in your error case (1.0 in the example) and what are min and max of value? You must have *huge* values for `value`, the range for `real` is typically from at least 1E-37 to 1E+37. (Or you introduced an independent problem somehow.) Maybe start a new question with all relevant details.

Comment: Hi @Erwin Brandstetter:, yes, you are right. My bad, didnt look the value range when copied from parent table. I fixed that problem. When I run on table with ~ 55K records, your solution runs ~ 4 secs where as SQL is running for ~ 6 mins. Thats a big difference and time difference drastically increasing as the table size grows. Thanks Erwin. Its clear on which way to go

Answer (score 4):

```
WITH tmp AS (
    SELECT *
        , sum(value) OVER (ORDER BY dt rows between current row and unbounded following) as forward_sum
    FROM sample
    ORDER BY dt)
SELECT t1.dt, t1.value
    , (t2.value + t1.forward_sum - t2.forward_sum) as "sum(value)"
    , t2.dt as "time_at_sum(value)_1" 
    , t2.dt - t1.dt as "Duration"
FROM tmp t1
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT * 
    FROM tmp t
    WHERE t1.forward_sum - t.forward_sum < 1
        AND (t.value + t1.forward_sum - t.forward_sum) >= 0.999
    ORDER BY dt DESC 
    LIMIT 1
    ) t2
ON TRUE
```

yields

```
| dt                  | value | sum(value) | time_at_sum(value)_1 | Duration |
|---------------------+-------+------------+----------------------+----------|
| 2019-01-20 00:29:43 |  0.29 |       1.01 | 2019-01-20 00:35:50  | 00:06:07 |
| 2019-01-20 00:35:06 |  0.31 |       1.31 | 2019-01-20 00:37:20  | 00:02:14 |
| 2019-01-20 00:35:50 |  0.41 |          1 | 2019-01-20 00:37:20  | 00:01:30 |
| 2019-01-20 00:36:32 |  0.26 |       1.01 | 2019-01-20 00:41:30  | 00:04:58 |
| 2019-01-20 00:37:20 |  0.33 |        1.1 | 2019-01-20 00:42:28  | 00:05:08 |
| 2019-01-20 00:41:30 |  0.42 |       1.29 | 2019-01-20 00:43:14  | 00:01:44 |
| 2019-01-20 00:42:28 |  0.35 |       1.12 | 2019-01-20 00:44:18  | 00:01:50 |
| 2019-01-20 00:43:14 |  0.52 |            |                      |          |
| 2019-01-20 00:44:18 |  0.25 |            |                      |          |
```

---

First compute a cumulative sum over the `value` column:

```
SELECT *
    , sum(value) OVER (ORDER BY dt rows between current row and unbounded following) as forward_sum
FROM sample
ORDER BY dt
```

which yields

```
| dt                  | value | forward_sum |
|---------------------+-------+-------------|
| 2019-01-20 00:29:43 |  0.29 |        3.14 |
| 2019-01-20 00:35:06 |  0.31 |        2.85 |
| 2019-01-20 00:35:50 |  0.41 |        2.54 |
| 2019-01-20 00:36:32 |  0.26 |        2.13 |
| 2019-01-20 00:37:20 |  0.33 |        1.87 |
| 2019-01-20 00:41:30 |  0.42 |        1.54 |
| 2019-01-20 00:42:28 |  0.35 |        1.12 |
| 2019-01-20 00:43:14 |  0.52 |        0.77 |
| 2019-01-20 00:44:18 |  0.25 |        0.25 |
```

Notice that subtracting two values from `forward_sum` corresponds to a partial sum over `value`s.
For example,

```
0.29 + 0.31 + 0.41 = 3.14 - 2.13
```

So the difference of `forward_sums` are going to play an important role, and we'll want to compare these differences to 1. We're going to want to join this table with itself, using a join condition like:

```
t1.forward_sum - t.forward_sum < 1
```

Let's see what happens if we use LEFT JOIN LATERAL. The critical thing to know about LEFT JOIN LATERAL is that the subquery to the right of a LATERAL join [has to be evaluated once for each row in the table on the left](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28557803/190597):

```
WITH tmp AS (
    SELECT *
        , sum(value) OVER (ORDER BY dt rows between current row and unbounded following) as forward_sum
    FROM sample
    ORDER BY dt)
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM tmp t1
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT * 
    FROM tmp t
    WHERE t1.forward_sum - t.forward_sum < 1
    ORDER BY dt DESC 
    LIMIT 1
    ) t2
ON TRUE
```

yields

```
| dt                  | value | forward_sum | dt                  | value | forward_sum |
|---------------------+-------+-------------+---------------------+-------+-------------|
| 2019-01-20 00:29:43 |  0.29 |        3.14 | 2019-01-20 00:35:50 |  0.41 |        2.54 |
| 2019-01-20 00:35:06 |  0.31 |        2.85 | 2019-01-20 00:37:20 |  0.33 |        1.87 |
| 2019-01-20 00:35:50 |  0.41 |        2.54 | 2019-01-20 00:37:20 |  0.33 |        1.87 |
| 2019-01-20 00:36:32 |  0.26 |        2.13 | 2019-01-20 00:41:30 |  0.42 |        1.54 |
| 2019-01-20 00:37:20 |  0.33 |        1.87 | 2019-01-20 00:42:28 |  0.35 |        1.12 |
| 2019-01-20 00:41:30 |  0.42 |        1.54 | 2019-01-20 00:43:14 |  0.52 |        0.77 |
| 2019-01-20 00:42:28 |  0.35 |        1.12 | 2019-01-20 00:44:18 |  0.25 |        0.25 |
| 2019-01-20 00:43:14 |  0.52 |        0.77 | 2019-01-20 00:44:18 |  0.25 |        0.25 |
| 2019-01-20 00:44:18 |  0.25 |        0.25 | 2019-01-20 00:44:18 |  0.25 |        0.25 |
```

Notice that we've guessed our way to the join condition which matches the
desired dates. Now it's just a matter of composing the right value expressions to
obtain the desired columns, `sum(value)`, `time_at_sum(value)_1`.

Comment: Added your smart query to my fiddle - for testing convenience: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e774e0003218d5142ba5db8def8be8a0

Comment: This is great. Thanks a lot for your helpl Unutbu. I was cracking my head for couple of days over this problem.