# Find first 3 orders for each customer

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, sql-limit

I am trying to find the *first 3 timestamps for each customer.*

Sample data for table `customer_orders`:

| customer_id | timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 6778 | '2022-01-01' |
| 6778 | '2022-02-05' |
| 5544 | '2022-04-01' |
| 6778 | '2022-02-04' |
| 5544 | '2022-04-03' |
| 5544 | '2022-04-02' |
| 5544 | '2022-01-01' |
| 6778 | '2021-01-01' |

Desired outcome:

| customer_id | timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 5544 | '2022-01-01' |
| 5544 | '2022-04-01' |
| 5544 | '2022-04-02' |
| 6778 | '2021-01-01' |
| 6778 | '2022-01-01' |
| 6778 | '2022-04-02' |

My query so far:

```
SELECT
    customer_id, 
    timestamp
FROM customer_orders
GROUP BY customer_id, timestamp
ORDER BY timestamp ASC
LIMIT 3
```

`LIMIT 3` limits to 3 rows overall. But I want 3 rows **per customer**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the window function [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/postgresql-row_number/) to numerate the columns of a given `PARTITION` (`customer_id` in your case) within a [`CTE`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-cte/) and in the outer query just filter the *n* records from this generated column:

```
WITH j AS (
  SELECT customer_id, timestamp,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY timestamp
                       RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS n
  FROM customer_orders
) 
SELECT customer_id, timestamp FROM j
WHERE n <= 3 
ORDER BY customer_id, timestamp
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d55bc238148448fb19cb01f01bcdb4a7)

Answer (score 0):

#### Faster window function

@Jim provided a valid solution. But there are subtle performance details. `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` is the default window frame, spelling it out is just noise. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS)

> The default framing option is `RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`, which is
> the same as `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`.

But `row_number()` operates on *rows* by definition, it's more efficient to use **`ROWS`** mode:

```
SELECT customer_id, timestamp
FROM  (
   SELECT row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY timestamp
                             ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS rn
        , customer_id, timestamp
   FROM   customer_orders
   ) sub
WHERE  rn <= 3 
ORDER  BY 1, 2;
```

An index like this is essential to sped it up:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON customer_orders (customer_id, timestamp);
```

I ran extensive tests on Postgres 13 and 14 with `ROWS` vs. `RANGE` mode, and `ROWS` is consistently ~ **20% faster** with an index-only scan. Quite a revelation for one of the most commonly used window functions!

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kHMyTMoY)

#### Optimized in Postgres 16

I eventually presented this case to the Postgres devs, and Postgres 16 has this optimization now built in! See:

- https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAApHDvohAKEtTXxq7Pc-ic2dKT8oZfbRKeEJP64M0B6%2BS88z%2BA%40mail.gmail.com

Meaning, in Postgres 16 (going forward), a plain `row_number()` is just as fast. In earlier versions adding the frame clause `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` makes it considerably faster.

#### Faster, yet

That said, if your table is big and there are many rows per customer, a different query style is **much faster**, yet - by orders of magnitude. We need the same index as above.

Ideally, you have a table `customers` with exactly one row per relevant `customer_id`. If you don't have it, create it. Then:

```sql
SELECT c.customer_id, o.timestamp
FROM   customers c
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT timestamp
   FROM   customer_orders o
   WHERE  o.customer_id = c.customer_id
   ORDER  BY o.timestamp
   LIMIT  3
   ) o
ORDER  BY 1, 2;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EFqZDVYM)

Related:

- [DISTINCT ON, but get the second row, not the first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72808864/distinct-on-but-get-the-second-row-not-the-first/72809058#72809058)
- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)
- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-row-per-user/25536748#25536748)