# DISTINCT ON, but get the second row, not the first

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm using PostgreSQL.
I want to select 1 row for every unique id, I have this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (station_id) *
FROM readings
ORDER BY station_id,reading_id DESC;
```

I have 2 tables:

`readings` (content isn't important, I hope):

```
station_id  reading_id    temp   air_pressure
--------------------------------------------
  147          100         10       800
  148          101         20       850
  149          102         30       900
  148          103         40       950
  148          104         50       1000
  147          105         60       1050
```

`stations` (content not important I hope):

```
id   station_name   lat   lng
-----------------------------
147      
148     
149
```

So `readings.station_id` and `station.id` in stations should be the same.

My query works, but now I want to select the **second** newest one (2nd highest id): ignore the first row (newest reading) and select the second.

Desired result based on above sample:

```
station_id   reading_id   temp   air_pressure
----------------------------------------------
   148          103        40        950        
   147          100        10        800
```

I want the row with the second highest `reading_id` for every `station_id` (second newest reading).

Would be nice if it won't select the ones where there is only one row, but not necessary.

I'm not sure how to achieve this. I've tried so much with `offset`, `limit` etc. also tried some nested select queries ...

I want to use `distinct on` because I need to select second row from every unique id. But if it's not possible with `distinct on`, it's alright.

Comment: With `DISTINCT ON(station_id)` there will be no second row for `station_id`. To your question add example data showing what you are starting with and what you want to end up with?

Comment: There are (very) efficient solutions. Is there a table `station` with one row per relevant `station_id`, too? Also: your version of Postgres, and the exact table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement)? And roughly how many rows per `station_id`? And what if there is just a single row per `station_id`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best query heavily depends on undisclosed information.

Assuming:

- current Postgres 14 (all should work since at least Postgres 9.3)
- large table (?)
- many rows per `station_id` (?)
- no duplicates on `(station_id, reading_id)` (?)
- a `stations` table with 1 row per station ✅
- `reading_id`is defined `NOT NULL`. (?)

```
SELECT r.*
FROM   station s
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT *
   FROM   readings r
   WHERE  r.station_id = s.station_id
   ORDER  BY reading_id DESC
   OFFSET 1
   LIMIT  1
   ) r
ORDER  BY r.station_id;  -- optional
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4c3784e20008a996fff822229eb2e0c0)*

You get no row for stations with less than two rows.

This is *very* efficient for more than a few rows per station and an index on `readings(station_id, reading_id DESC)`.

About the `LATERAL` join:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

**If** you don't have a separate `stations` table, see:

- [How to get the second highest value per group?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/303320/3684)

**If** there can be duplicates (doesn't seem to be the case), and/or there are only few rows per group, this might be better:

```
SELECT (r).*
FROM  (
   SELECT r, dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY station_id
                                ORDER BY reading_id DESC) AS rnk
   FROM   readings r
   ) r
WHERE  rnk = 2;
```

Here, you get no row for stations with less than two distinct `reading_id`. But possibly more than one per station that tie for second place.

Related:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)
- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-row-per-user/25536748#25536748)

Comment: If I didn't guess right, update your question to be more specific.

Comment: So, i updated my question a bit. Now your code doesn't work for me, probably because im not sure what is this "r" after cross join literal ()? Shouldn't be there just nothing after )?Because there is the select statement?  Im not sure, would be nice if  you could updated it to my tables now.

Comment: nvm, it works now. Had a typo. Thank you!!

Comment: I clarified a bit.