Find N latest rows for each row in the main table
For each row in table line there can be many rows in table line_version. I need to find only N (let's say 2) "latest" rows for each line row. Latest here means the largest IDs.
For example, that's how line_version table rows look like (line_id references the line table):
  id   | line_id 
-------+---------
 10    |   1
 20    |   1
 30    |   1
 40    |   1
 50    |   2
 60    |   2
 70    |   2

Looking for the 2 latest line_version row IDs per line row, it should be (30, 40, 60, 70).
Globally, I can get 2 latest ones by simply doing:
SELECT id from line_version ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2

But how can I get the latest 2 per line_id?

We can assume Postgres 16, all columns in table line_version defined NOT NULL,  no duplicates on (line_id, id), and an existing table line holding line_id as primary key

I took the liberty to clarify your question as I understand it. Please revise if I didn't get it right.

@ErwinBrandstetter good point about postgres version. Forgot to mention it. Its actually 13. Other assumptions are correct.

YOu can use the below with condition rownumber>=count1-(N-1).The sql fiddle here.For last row you can use rownumber>=count1.last two rows rownumber>=count1-1,three rows rownumber>=count1-2
with data as (select 

     10 id   ,  1 line_id union all
     select 20    ,   1 union all
     select 30    ,   1 union all
     select 40    ,   1 union all
     select 50    ,  2 union all
     select 60    ,   2 union all
    select  70    ,   2),
    subset as (select a.*,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by line_id order by id ) rownumber,count(id) over(partition by line_id) count1 from data a)
    select id,line_id from subset where rownumber>=count1-1;

To improve the performance you can do away with the count1 with the below using rownumber<=N.
        with data as (select 

     10 id   ,  1 line_id union all
     select 20    ,   1 union all
     select 30    ,   1 union all
     select 40    ,   1 union all
     select 50    ,  2 union all
     select 60    ,   2 union all
    select  70    ,   2),
    subset as (select a.*,ROW_NUMBER() 
    over(partition by line_id order by id desc) 
    rownumber from data a)
    select id,line_id from subset 
    where rownumber<=2 order by line_id,id;


It seems to count correctly, but on large set, it is quite slow. And in my case, there are millions of rows.. Takes over 20s on ~4 million rows.

can you try adding a LIMIT clause with value of count of line_id *N

If you mean after subset.rownumber >= subset.count1-1, adding limit like 2, has no effect.

updated the answer to do away with count1

Looks like performance is still the same, with both variants.

what is the actual value of N and are there any filters in the original query

https://dbfiddle.uk/AC0D8GKU as per analysis filtering before getting the rows is faster than after getting the rows

Many rows per line
If there are substantially more versions than just the two per line, avoid a sequential scan over line_version. This query using a LATERAL subquery does just that, and should be much more efficient:
SELECT lv.*
FROM   line l
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT lv.id
   FROM   line_version lv
   WHERE  lv.line_id = l.line_id
   ORDER  BY lv.id DESC NULLS LAST
   LIMIT  2  -- your pick!
   ) lv
-- ORDER BY ???

fiddle
I added NULLS LAST mainly to defend against possible null values, which you haven't ruled out. See:

Sort by column ASC, but NULL values first?

Select first row in each GROUP BY group?


Be sure to have an index on line_version with line_id as leading index field. Ideally:
CREATE INDEX line_version_line_id_id_idx ON line_version(line_id DESC NULLS LAST) INCLUDE (id);

See:

Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user
What is the difference between a LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?
Advantage of using INCLUDE as against adding the column in INDEX for covering index

Few rows per line
For few rows per line, a subquery with row_number() like provided by psaraj12 should be the optimum. Except, in versions before Postgres 16, you can speed it up with a window frame in ROWS mode. See:

Find first 3 orders for each customer


strangely this one seems to be about 2x slower than suggested answer by psaraj12. Do note line_id is indexed. Also id is guaranteed to not be NULL.

@Andrius: Key to the best query are basic cardinalities: how many rows in each table, how many distinct line_id. For only few rows per line_id, a sequential scan on line_version is typically faster. Other factors like bloat, avg. row size, server config, Postgres version, exact index def. also play a role ...

there are ~1kk lines rows and ~4kk line_version rows. So about 4 versions for single line on average.

Well, that's few. A sequential scan will typically be fastest. My first query pays for many rows per line. Or when you filter a small subset. You can still speed up the the query with row_number(), while you are on Postgres 13. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72533266/find-first-3-orders-for-each-customer/72824267#72824267
